# Testing the pseudo-element of a referenced styled component

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, styled-components

I have a toggle switch where my styled input component references my styled label component

```
const Knob = styled.span`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3.25rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: ${basic[600]};
  cursor: pointer;
  &::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 1.7rem;
    height: 1.7rem;
    margin: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
`;

const Toggle = styled.label`
  position: relative;
  ${applyStyleModifiers(BUTTON_MODIFIERS_STATUS)};
`;

const Check = styled.input`
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  &:checked + ${Knob} {
    background: ${primary[500]};
    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 1.7rem;
      height: 1.7rem;
      margin-left: 1.3125rem;
      transition: 0.2s;
    }
  }
`;
```

When the `Check` component is checked the `Knob` component has some of its styles updated.
I want to test the styles of the pseudo-element before and after the checkbox is clicked.

I am able to successfully test styles before

```
    const { getByTestId } = render(<ToggleSwitch ariaLabel="primary" />);
    const toggle = getByTestId("toggle-switch");
    const checkbox = getByTestId("toggle-checkbox");
    expect(toggle).toHaveStyleRule("border-radius", "50%", {
      modifier: "&::after",
    });
```

After I click the checkbox I am still able to test the background of the `Knob` component using `toHaveStyle` rather than `toHaveStyleRule` as this is not part of the pseudo-element `:after`.

```
   expect(checkbox.checked).toEqual(false);
    fireEvent.click(checkbox);
    expect(checkbox.checked).toEqual(true);

    expect(toggle).toHaveStyle(`background : ${primary[500]}`);
```

However I am not able to test any of the changes on the pseudo-element.

```
    expect(toggle).toHaveStyleRule("margin", "1.3125rem", {
      modifier: "&::after",
    });
```

The above does not work and tells me that the expected `margin` is still 3px. What I believe I need to do is use `toHaveStyle` and attach the `&::after` modifier, but I have had no success with this yet.

When I try

```
expect(toggle).toHaveStyle(`margin : 1.3125rem`, { modifier: "&::after" });
```

My test fails and indicated margin is not found on this component.